# Finding every $n$ such that $n\times$ ('reverse' number of $n)=m^2$ such as $1584\times 4851={2772}^2$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, computational-mathematics

Let $r(n)$ be the 'reverse' number of $n$ in the decimal system. For example, $r(1234)=4321$.

Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : Can we find every $n(\in\mathbb N)$, which is **not** a square number, such that
>   $$n\times r(n)=\text{a square number ?} $$

**Motivation** : First, I got interested in the followings : 
$$169\times 961={403}^2, 144\times 441={252}^2$$
Note that these examples are **not** what we want because each of $n$ is a square number. These got me interested in the above question. Then, I've already found the followings by using computer :

$$1584\times 4851={2772}^2$$
$$15984\times 48951={27972}^2$$

Then, I realized that these are the special cases of the following equation :

$$\begin{align}1599\cdots 984\times 4899\cdots 951={2799\cdots 972}^2\qquad(\star)\end{align}$$
Note that each of $99\cdots 9$ has $m$ consective $9$s where $m$ is a non-negative integer.

We can see that $(\star)$ is true because
$$16\cdot({10}^{m+2}-1)\times 49\cdot({10}^{m+2}-1)=\{28\cdot({10}^{m+2}-1)\}^2.$$

However, I don't have any good idea for finding every possible $n$. Can anyone help?

Comment: the first $36$ are given in OEIS  at http://oeis.org/A082994 with a few references.  The search seems to have quit at $100,000$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thank you very much for nice information.